# How to say two java objects are equal with case ignore?

Tags: java

I have two java user defined java objects, how can i make these two objects to return same references with case ignore

**Sample code:**

```
public class compare{

    private String name;
    private Integer number;
}
```

Comment: in case the references are the same, the string must be the same.

Comment: You must implement your own hashcode (and equals), and in the hashcode function make sure name is compared case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must override hashcode and equals to properly compare two objects.    The following is an IDE generated hashCode and equals method.

```
class A
    {
        @Override
        public int hashCode()
        {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((number == null) ? 0 : number.hashCode());
        return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        A other = (A) obj;
        if (name == null)
        {
            if (other.name != null)
            return false;
        }
        else if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(other.name))
            return false;
        if (number == null)
        {
            if (other.number != null)
            return false;
        }
        else if (!number.equals(other.number))
            return false;
        return true;
        }
        String name;
        Integer number;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

java.lang.String has a method for this:
    myString.equalsIgnoreCase("MyStRiNg");

If this is not what you are looking for please be more specific.